# Is there a way how a request bean cound interact with a session bean?

Tags: jsp, session, javabeans

Let's say I have a login created and I have username and other attributes in access. In the further process I do not want to ask the same attributes again all the time (because DB access is expensive).
So I need to store those data within the session scope. Up to this point this is common usage.
But how to change a value in the session bean if I want to this within a request bean?
E.g. I want to change a counter value in the session scope, which I got from the DB.
As far as I know the request bean does not know about sessions or requests and it should not know by design.
So, how can I solve the problem?
Or do I miss s.th.?